# Is there a FunctionType with named arguments in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

In LLVM, a function looks like this:

```
define i32 @foo(i32, i32)
```

By playing with `lli`, I noticed that this is also accepted:

```
define i32 @foo(i32 %first-arg, i32 %second-arg)
```

and then the arguments are accessible from the given names.

How should I generate such a function with named arguments using the C++ API? I checked the documentation and it seems that there's no way to supply names to `FunctionType::get` as its second argument is of type `ArrayRef<Type *>` where there isn't a field for name (or `Twine`).

Comment: Btw, I cribbed [the link from your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/reinstate-monica) and added it to my own now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names aren't part of the type. In terms of types, each and every i32 is the same. However, you can set a function argument's name without affecting the type, just like you can set the function's name. I cribbed a for loop from an mezozoic version of LLVM and added a setName() call, and that worked:

```
for (Function::arg_iterator a = foo->arg_begin(), ae = foo->arg_end();
     a != ae;
     ++a) {
  …
  a->setName(bar->name);
  …
}
```

I assume there's a prettier way to write that loop now.