# Naming convention to map "c" function arguments to .ll prototype

Tags: clang, llvm

I would like to understand how arguments are passed to function in .ll textual format.

My c function prototype looks like :

```
int power(int n, int r)
```

clang (followed by opt) compiles to :

```
define i32 @power(i32, i32) #0 {
```

"n" and "r" **have vanished** ! I need them here, in the **textual IR**!

Otherwise, it is not trivial to understand how the arguments are actually used.

Or maybe there is an obscure convention like "%1" is the first argument of the function, etc, but that does not seem so evident.

Any idea ?

Is there a naming convention or whatever to understand how my "c" arguments mapped to .ll names, in the **function header** ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such convention, no, and the names don't really map in that direction since IR has values rather than variables.

```
int a = 42;
while(b())
   a += c();
d(a);
```

There is one variable called a, but the IR will probably contain four values that correspond to a's values at the end of the line 1, start of line 3, end of line 3 and start of line 4.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58957270) shows how to add names. Whether to do that is up to you, and if you want to do it, you have to find a naming scheme too. "a.line4.column0" or anything else.

Comment: Thx, but my question is about textual representation strictly (not c++ way to manipulate the ir). Imagine I need to explain .ll to a student. Where have the arguments gone ?

Comment: The arguments have become values, which may be named but need not be. Name them if you want, it doesn't matter, LLVM won't use the names. An argument may have turned into one value, or into several.

Comment: `int a(int b){while(c()) b += d(); return b;}` is a function whose only argument turns into several values.

Comment: My concern is about the completeness of the textual description : in previous llvm versions (1 year ago or so) the names of the arguments were present in the header. I think your focus is on SSA (no ?), which is not a problem (nor the solution) to me.

Comment: I suppose I don't understand what you're getting at... as I understand it, IR is intended to be an SSA language, its textual representation if it captures the same infornmation as in the .bc file, and both IR and its textuatl representation are explicitly not intended to capture all aspects of the source language from which a given .bc (or .ll) file was compiled. Perhaps you might find the answer in the git log for the frontend that doesn't call Argument::setName() and once did. Clang, I suppose.

Comment: Thx for the help. As far as I understand, you seem to "accept" that it is now impossible to reconstitute the data dependencies by simply reading the ll text ?

Comment: Well, the language and frontend I work with (not C/Clang) can't be reconstituted for at least three reasons. Probably more, since I could think of three right away. What difference does a fourth reason make, when something already is impossible thrice over?